# Create laravel blade horizontal table view from array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have an Laravel DB::Query that give me result like this

```
 arrayResult = array('nip' => '12345678', 'nama' => 'rachmat', 'month' => '1', 'sum' => 13'),
               array('nip' => '12345678', 'nama' => 'rachmat', 'month' => '3', 'sum' => 10'),
               array('nip' => '12345678', 'nama' => 'rachmat', 'month' => '8', 'sum' => 9'));
```

then i create multidimensional array like this

```
foreach ($pegawai as $key ) {
            $peg[$key->nip]['nama'] = $key->nama;
            $peg[$key->nip]['nip'] = $key->nip;
            $peg[$key->nip]['month'][$key->month] = $key->sum;

        }
```

the result of the array is like this

```
array(12345678
    ('nama' => 'Rachmat', 
     'nip' => '12345678', 
     Month(1 => 13,
           3 => 10,
           8 => 9)));
```

then i view it in the blade table like this :

```
@foreach($peg as $st)
   <tr>
       <td style="text-align: center;">{{$no++}}</td>
       <td>{{$st['nama']}}<br>{{$st['nip']}}</td>    
       @foreach($st['bulan'] as $a => $value)     
       <td style="text-align: center;"> {{ $value }}   </td>
       @endforeach
       </tr>
@endforeach
```

the problem is the $value data shown in a sequence, not in accordance with the month of the data.

my view :

```html
<table id="table" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" >
                <thead>
                  <tr class="tableheader">
                  <th style="width:10px" rowspan="2" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">#</th>
                  <th rowspan="2" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">Nama Pegawai</th>
                  <th colspan="12" style="text-align: center;">Bulan</th>
                  </tr> 
                  <tr>
                    <th style="text-align: center;">January</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center;">February</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center;">March</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center;">April</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center;">May</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center;">June</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center;">July</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center;">August</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center;">Sept</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center;">Okt</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center;">Nop</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center;">Dec</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                      <td style="text-align: center;">1</td>
                      <td>Rachmat<br>123456</td>             
                    <td style="text-align: center;"> 13   </td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">  10 </td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;"> 9  </td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">   </td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">   </td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">   </td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">   </td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">  </td>
         
                  </tr>

                </tbody>
                </table>
```

what i want :

```html
<table id="table" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" >
                <thead>
                  <tr class="tableheader">
                  <th style="width:10px" rowspan="2" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">#</th>
                  <th rowspan="2" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">Nama Pegawai</th>
                  <th colspan="12" style="text-align: center;">Bulan</th>
                  </tr> 
                  <tr>
                    <th style="text-align: center;">January</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center;">February</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center;">March</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center;">April</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center;">May</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center;">June</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center;">July</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center;">August</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center;">Sept</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center;">Okt</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center;">Nop</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center;">Dec</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                      <td style="text-align: center;">1</td>
                      <td>Rachmat<br>123456</td>             
                    <td style="text-align: center;"> 13   </td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">   </td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;"> 10  </td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">   </td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">   </td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">   </td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">   </td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;"> 9  </td>
         
                  </tr>

                </tbody>
                </table>
```

all help appriciated

Comment: `$st['bulan']` doesn't existed, do you mean `$st['month']` ?

Comment: sorry, try to change the word to english... thx for the answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
@foreach($peg as $st)
   <tr>
       <td style="text-align: center;">{{$no++}}</td>
       <td>{{$st['nama']}}<br>{{$st['nip']}}</td>  

       @for($i = 1, $i <= 12, $i++)
          <td style="text-align: center;"> {{ isset($st['month'][$i]) ? $st['month'][$i] : "" }}   </td>
       @endfor

   </tr>
 @endforeach
```

Comment: should be `{{ isset($st['month'][$i]) ? $st['month'][$i] : "" }}`

Answer (score 1):

> how to convert this on vue js?

```
 @foreach($peg as $st)
   <tr>
       <td style="text-align: center;">{{$no++}}</td>
       <td>{{$st['nama']}}<br>{{$st['nip']}}</td>  

       @for($i = 1, $i <= 12, $i++)
          <td style="text-align: center;"> {{ isset($st['month'][$i]) ? $st['month'][$i] : "" }}   </td>
       @endfor

   </tr>
 @endforeach
```